# Are a Druid's Tree Shape ability and the spell "Entangle" compatible for a spell combo?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, druid

The [Tree Shape](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/treeShape.html) spell indicates that a Druid (or other character with the spell or ability) can turn into a *"large living tree or shrub"* and that the *"exact type of tree, as well as its appearance is completely under [that character's] control"*:

> This spell allows you to assume the form of a Large living tree or
>   shrub or a Large dead tree trunk with a small number of limbs. The
>   exact type of tree, as well as its appearance, is completely under
>   your control.

The [Entangle](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/entangle.html) spell indicates that *"tall grass, weeds, and other plants"* can be used for the effect:

> This spell causes tall grass, weeds, and other plants to wrap around
>   creatures in the area of effect or those that enter the area.

My main question is: can a Druid in tree form be used in combination with another character casting Entangle, in order to produce the same effects as Entangle, but in an area where there is no naturally-occurring other vegetation (of significant note), for example in a building?

If yes, could the Druid choose to be a thorny bush and gain the additional effects mentioned in the Entangle spell?

> If the plants in the area are covered in thorns, those in the area
>   take 1 point of damage each time they fail a save against the entangle
>   or fail a check made to break free.

EDIT: To clarify, the *Entangle* spell would be cast by another character, not the Druid.

Answer (score 4):

RAW it is probably a No.

[Tree shape](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/treeShape.html) does not turn you into a plant. It just magically disguises you.

> Even the closest inspection cannot reveal that the **tree in question is
>   actually a magically concealed creature**

However, this is something you should talk to your GM about.

Comment: The phrase in question doesn't definitively mean that you are indeed not for all intents and purposes a tree.  The mere means of the spell being transmutation seems to go against such a classification as simple concealment in terms of just a disguise.

Comment: The transmutation school can be explained simply by the fact that the spell provides +10 natural armor and modifies your move speed. The spell says nothing about transforming you into a 'plant' (treated as an object by the rules) or  a creature with the 'plant' subtype (which may or may not even be affected by entangle spell).

Comment: The lack of clarity is the reason for the lack of the -1.  But it could indeed be argued either way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. As Tree Shape is a **Transmutation** spell and not an Illusion spell the druid is technically a valid plant, however the Entangle then becomes kind of a self-shape-change, as it modifies the druid's current form, which might grant him a save against it.

So a GM could decide that as long as the druid *willingly* allowing that spell to take form, it can use those roots to entangle enemies (with the probable side-effect of not being able to move otherwise, basically entangling the druid as well, and shaping back might simply fail, end the Entangle or have worse effects), while enemy casters might allow the druid a fort save to resist the spell completely (even though plants usually don't get one).

Comment: Eh...I don't like the lack of rules support in this answer. Especially given that Entangle doesn't indicate that it affects plant creatures in the fashion you describe.

Comment: Probably because there is no rule for this specific case. ;)
The spell causes the Druid to assume the form of a living or dead tree, which is not a plant creature, but a creature shape-changed into a plant. So the question would rather be: if I polymorph someone into a tree, can I use that for Entangle?

Comment: +1 for the point about Transmute vs Illusion. Although not backed-up by rules in your answer, I believe there is a certain logical/implicit difference between the schools of magic.

Answer (score 2):

**Probably Not**

Not because the druid isn't a plant, mind you. But because he's not *enough plant* to cover the entire area of the spell. *Entangle*'s spread is quite the bit larger than a single tree's space.

Comment: Okay, but if we accept the area of effect would be significantly reduced, you're saying that it could be used in combo, if the Druid was (for example) within normal melee range of the intended target at the time?

Comment: There's no strict if/then on RAW; spells with conditions like this tend to be pretty rare. I suppose you might look into *Transmute Rock to Mud* and *Transmute Rock to Lava* to see precedents on the wording? I'm inclined to say, however, that the *Entangle* fails to operate because of the way 3.PF treats prerequisites; namely, you cannot use or take an option if you fail to meet the pre-reqs, even if you already have it. *Entangle* has a prerequisite built into its spell description - there are plants within its area - and failing to meet that fizzles the spell. This is, however, my opinion.

Comment: Good point on pre-requisites. Although in this case a single tree is still 'within' the area. The fact that the spell definition also mentions that other ground in the AoE is classed as difficult terrain reinforces the fact that the whole 40' radius area does not have to be covered in vegetation. I'll check out those other spells, good suggestion.

Comment: The Polymorph Any Object spell does not list Tree Form as a spell it can emulate, which makes me question whether the druid counts as a plant when using Tree Form.

Answer (score -1):

Englangle requires verbal, somatic and divine focus.  I'd rule that is pretty hard to pull off when in tree form.  If the Druid had the ability to speak with plants (magic or linguistic), and became a plant clearly bearing some visible marking of the druid's ethos/clan/divine power/enclave, then I'd allow a spellcraft for the casting - DC probably at about a 17-20.

Comment: I may not have made this clear, but I was assuming that another character would be casting Entangle.